# php preg_replace or expression replace all but first match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi guys could you please help me to resolve this riddle?

I have an array of keywords pretty big one that I use to match those keywords in content.

Example: $array('game','gamers','gaming'); etc...

I am using this foreach method to loop though each keyword and match it against content but in some cases content can be really big and more than 50 keywords and more than 20 posts per page slows the site down dramatically.

```
foreach($array as $key => $vall)
{

$pattern = '/\b'.$vall.'\b/';

$data['content'] = preg_replace($pattern, " <a style=\"font-weight: bold;color:rgb(20, 23, 26);\" href=\"".$url."\">".$vall."</a>", $data['content'],1);    
}
```

The good thing about is that I can specify replace limit to one means that it will not replace all instances of that keyword.

The method above is not performance effective.

My other approach is this but there is an issue. I can't specify limit.

```
$pattern = '/\bgamers|gaming|gamer\b/';
$data['content'] = preg_replace($pattern, " <a style=\"font-weight: bold;color:rgb(20, 23, 26);\" href=\"".$url."\">$0</a>", $data['content']);
```

The method above works great but it replaces all instances of matched keywords.

Question. How can I add to pattern keywords separated by or expression and then replace only first match of each keyword.

Update.

```
$string = 'I am a gamer and I love playing video games. Video games are awesome. I have being a gamer for a long time. I love to hang-out with other gamer buddies of mine.';

$keyWordsToMatch = 'gamer,games';
```

For the output it needs to replace only forst instance of $keyWordsToMatch.

Like this:

```
$string = 'I am a (gamer)_replace and I love playing video (games)_replace. Video games are awesome. I have being a gamer for a long time. I love to hang-out with other gamer buddies of mine.';
```

Comment: Can you post a _very simple_ sample of your input data, along with what you want for the output, I'm not completely clear on the "all but first" portion.

Comment: `$pattern = '/\bgamers|gaming|gamer\b/';` is a typo. You need `$pattern = '/\b(?:gamers|gaming|gamer)\b/';`

Comment: Thanks guys I have update my question. Sorry I have not preceded my self correctly.

Comment: How do i use this $pattern = '/\b(?:gamers|gaming|gamer)\b/';

Comment: You *are* already using it, `$data['content'] = preg_replace($pattern, " <a style=\"font-weight: bold;color:rgb(20, 23, 26);\" href=\"".$url."\">$0</a>", $data['content']);`. But I guess the problem is with the number of words, the pattern gets too long for PCRE.

Comment: Thanks. How its usually done? When you got a bit list of words to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this by using `preg_replace_callback` and keeping track of  keywords you found. I've also added the grouping the @Wiktor Stribiżew suggested, and I personally like to use named-captures in RegEx.

See the comments for additional details

```php
$string = 'gamer thing gamer games test games';
$pattern = '/\b(?<keyword>gamer|games)\b/';

// We'll append to this array after we use a given keyword
$usedKeywords = [];
$finalString = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,

    // Remember to capture the array by-ref
    static function (array $matches) use (&$usedKeywords) {
        $thisKeyword = $matches['keyword'];
        if (in_array($thisKeyword, $usedKeywords, true)) {
            return $thisKeyword;
        }

        $usedKeywords[] = $thisKeyword;
        
        // Do your replacement here
        return '~'.$thisKeyword.'~';

    },
    $string
);

print_r($finalString);
```

The output is:

`~gamer~ thing gamer ~games~ test games`

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/j40Oq

Comment: Thank you so much. Man people around here are smart.

Comment: Works like a charm. Exactly what i was looking for and its fast too.

Comment: The idea is good but the use of `in_array()` drives to the same problem when the number of keywords grows. You can avoid the problem building an associative array where keys are keywords and values whatever you want, then you can test if a keyword "is in the array" using `array_key_exists()` that is from far faster. Or better, use a [Ds/Set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) to store the keywords.

Comment: Although I don't disagree that for large sets `in_array` is slower than others, the OP mentioned 50 as their number for "big", so I would be surprised if anything would be measurable.